# Can't use Spring tool suite or Eclipse with Spring Plugin! Multiple errors on start

Tags: macos, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to learn Spring and i have been 4 days trying to use Spring Tool Suite without success.

My SO is MacOs 10.9. I think that i installed the x64 jdk and the x64 jre. But i don't know how to check it.

The STS is the latest and the x64 version.

I do a fresh install of STS and on start i got the following error "Can't read the rss feed". Ok, i don't mind about the rss feed. But then, i try to create a new Spring MVC Application with the wizzard. I just select Spring MVC Project and give it a starting package and i got 3 exceptions.

1:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'springMVC2'.
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

2: Same as 1

3:

```
Error during build of project [springMVC2]
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'springMVC2'.
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (/Users/Carlos/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Please any help to get it working. I'm desesperating. Can't even start to play with it. I tried with eclipse kepler and spring plugin but i got the same error.

Comment: Your problem isn't with eclipse or STS. It would fail also with any other IDE using Maven. Your maven repository seems invalid/corrupted. Remove the offending plugins from the repository and try again, or remove your whole repository (this will download all needed dependencies again).

Comment: Thank you. It's working now!!! BTW. Whats the best web server for Spring Development?